# How do I loop through all files in my directory to get the average of each files data into one dataframe?

Tags: r, for-loop, directory, average, rbind

I have about 100 files in my path/directory. My objective is to loop through all of them and have a single output dataframe or file which has the names of all these files and the respective averages.

Reprex: All files are named as cities

```
Aberdeen
New York
Spain
Milan
Delhi
Etc

library(data.table) 
setwd("C:/Users/jt/Desktop/zzz/weatherdata")
files <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/jt/Desktop/zzz/weatherdata",pattern = ".csv")
temp <- lapply(files, fread, sep=",")
data <- rbindlist( temp )
```

As you can see I tried to call all of them as one dataframe

In each file there is information :

```
> data
        date_time maxtempC mintempC totalSnow_cm sunHour uvIndex uvIndex
    1: 2018-01-11        5        3            0     5.8       2       2
    2: 2018-01-12        7        3            0     5.8       2       2
    3: 2018-01-13        6        5            0     1.8       2       2
    4: 2018-01-14        6        4            0     1.8       2       2
    5: 2018-01-15        7        2            0     5.8       2       2
```

I want to write a loop that goes through each file in this directory calculates the average of these values(max temp,mintemp,sunhour,etc) and appends it to a single file that has all the names of these cities with their respective averages for each of these headers. Is there a way this can be done in R?

Comment: What is the issue in the current approach

Comment: I do not have an approach except for binding it into one DF like I have here

Comment: Do you need to average across or within

Comment: I need average within each file for all files in my path

Comment: Can you check the solution I possted below

Answer (score 0):

An option is

```
library(data.table)     
rbindlist(lapply(files, function(x) fread(x)[, 
    lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols = -1][, city := .sub("\\.csv$", "", x)][])
```

---

Another option is `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
imap_dfr(files, ~ fread(.x) %>%
                summarise_if(is.numeric, mean)%>%
                mutate(city = .y))
```

Comment: Is stuck in a loop

Comment: @user10007925. Not clear about your comment.  Is it an error?

Comment: It does not run and just shows the + sign. Do I have to edit the code "\\.csv$"? Or can I use this as it is? not familiar with the syntax

Comment: in the tidyverse option I want it not to mutate to the same file but I want all the cities and their respective averages to append to a new file

Comment: Error in imap_dfr(files, ~fread(.x) %>% summarise_if(is.numeric, mean) %>%  : 
  could not find function "imap_dfr"

Comment: @user10007925. it is from `purrr`.  I can't find the issue in the code though